# where is the pressure switch on a 3/4hp pump?

Tags: plumbing

The pressure in my 3/4hp pump reads 38 the pump runs 5 + minutes, shuts off,turns on and repeates itself.

Comment: The pressure switch likely isn’t the problem.  How cold is it where you are?  Is this a deep well pump, shallow well pump? Or something else?

Comment: -10 (cold as HELL) yes a deep well pump,it is located in my basement

Comment: You probably have a frozen pipes.  I've got 2 froze this morning and never had any freeze problems in the 5 years I've been in my current house.

Comment: I have running water out of all the faucets in my house.Are you thinking underground from the well to the house?

Comment: If that pipe is partially frozen, and your pump is inside (as opposed to submerged in the well) then it could cause short cycling.  I'd run lots of water and see if that will thaw it/solve it.

Comment: Where are you located?I am in Bangor Maine

Comment: I'm not close, Missouri. We had -8 last night tho.

Comment: I am ready for winter

Comment: What should the pressure be set at?

Comment: It depends on your system and pump. Like I said at the start, it's likely not the problem.  Pressure switches can fail, but rarely do.  And rarely need to be adjusted after initial installation.

Comment: How do i build up pressure in my air-tank next to my pump